# How to filter in two deep arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm looking to filter in two deep arrays, actually my JSON:

```
{
  "0": {
    "product":[{
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Rice"
    },
    {
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Pasta"
    }]
  },
  "1": {
    "product":[{
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Milk"
    }]
  }
}
```

I would like to get something like that when I filter with the word "ric":

```
{
  "0": {
    "product":[{
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Rice"
    }]
  }
}
```

But I got this result:

```
{
  "0": {
    "product":[{
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Rice"
    },
    {
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Pasta"
    }]
  }
}
```

My code:

**dataSort.categories** = the json and
**event.target.value.toLowerCase()** = the specific word

```js
dataSort.categories.filter(s => s.products.find(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())));
```

Comment: Your data is not an array

Comment: ?? My data is an array, got 2 element in the first, 0 and 1

Comment: @RaphaelM `{` - Object `[` - array

Comment: `product` is an array - the outer object is a map with numeric keys. Sort of like an array, but not an array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with a combination of `reduce` and `filter`

```js
var input = {
  "0": {
    "product":[{
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Rice"
    },
    {
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Pasta"
    }]
  },
  "1": {
    "product":[{
      "uuid":"uid",
      "name":"Milk"
    }]
  }
}

var search = "ric"

var result = Object.entries(input).reduce( (acc, [key,val]) => {
  found = val.product.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
  if(found.length){
    acc[key] = {...val, product: found}
  }
  return acc
},{})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many approach to do this, one is to map your top level array to the subArrays filtered results then filter it after:

```
dataSort.categories
  .map(s => s.products.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())))
  .filter(s => !!s.products.length);
```

You may also prefer to get a "flat" array as result because it is easier to use after :

```
dataSort.categories
  .reduce((acc, s) => [...acc, s.products.filter(p => p.name.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase()))], []);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please find below the code to filter out values inside the `product.name` and only return the value which are matching the equality condition in `product` array.

```js
const json = [
  {
    product: [
      {
        uuid: "uid",
        name: "Rice",
      },
      {
        uuid: "uid",
        name: "Pasta",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: [
      {
        uuid: "uid",
        name: "Milk",
      },
    ],
  },
];
const inputValue = "rIc";
const filteredArray = [];

json.map((s) => {
  const item = s.product.find((p) =>
    p.name.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase())
  );
  item && filteredArray.push({ product: item });
});

console.dir(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Urgh why mangle an array with `map` when `reduce` exists!

Answer (score -1):

Your dataset is an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is an Array method. You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) by looping on the object values by [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) then filter your products array.

```js
const data = {
  '0': {
    product: [
      {
        uuid: 'uid',
        name: 'Rice',
      },
      {
        uuid: 'uid',
        name: 'Pasta',
      },
    ],
  },
  '1': {
    product: [
      {
        uuid: 'uid',
        name: 'Milk',
      },
    ],
  },
};

const keyword = 'ric';
const dataset = Object.values(data);
const results = dataset.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  const search = keyword.toLowerCase();

  const product = item.product.filter(product => product.name.toLowerCase().includes(search));
  if (product.length) acc[index] = { ...item, product };

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(results);
```